# Why are test functions in the definition of weak derivatives required to be $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

Recall that a function $u \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(a,b)$ is said to be *weakly differentiable* with *weak derivative* $\nu$ if the equation
\begin{align}
    \int_{a}^{b} u(x) \phi'(x) dx
    = - \int_{a}^{b} v(x) \phi(x) dx,
\end{align}
holds for all $\phi \in \mathcal{C}_{\text{c}}^{\infty}(a,b)$.

> In understand we why need $\phi$ to be compactly supported but why do we require our test functions $\phi$ to be differentiable infinitely many times?

The definition per se only needs $\phi \in \mathcal{C}^1(a,b)\cap\mathcal{C}[a,b]$, right?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are correct. But often we want more than one derivative because the differential equation that we want to solve weakly has more derivatives.

Comment: By the way, $\mathcal{C}^1(a,b) \subseteq \mathcal{C}[a,b]$ so there's no need to take the intersection of these.

Comment: @md2perpe I don't think so. Consider $a = 0, b = 1$ and $$f: [0,1] \to [0,1], \ x \mapsto \begin{cases} 0, & x \in (0,1), \\ 1, & x \in \{0,1\} \end{cases}.$$

Comment: You are right; I didn't notice that one interval was open and the other closed.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I guess it depends on your interpretation of what it means for $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ to be in $C^1(,a,b)$.  Notice, however, that every $f \in C^1(a,b)$ is uniformly continuous, so each $f$ has a unique extension to $C[a,b]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of a weak derivative comes from a more general setup called the theory of distributions also called theory of generalized functions formalized by the French mathematician Laurent Schwartz in the 1940's.

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. We define the space of distributions $\mathcal D'(\Omega)$ as being the topological dual of the space of test functions $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$. For more details about this topology you can refer to Walter Rudin's *Functional Analysis* (pp. 151-153). 
For a given distribution $\tau$, its weak i-th derivative $\partial_{x_{i}}\tau$ in the sense of distributions is defined as  $$\begin{equation} \forall \phi  \in C^\infty_c(\Omega) \;\;\langle\partial_{x_{i}}\tau, \phi\rangle \;:= -\langle\tau, \partial_{x_{i}}\phi\rangle \end{equation}$$
To come back to your question, there is a canonical injection of the space $L^1_{loc}(\Omega)\hookrightarrow \mathcal D'(\Omega)$, indeed one can show that $$\langle f,\phi\rangle \;= \int_{\Omega} f\phi$$ for $f \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ is a distribution. Then we *define* a weak derivative for an $L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ function as its derivative in the sense of distributions: 
$$\forall \phi \in C^\infty_c(\Omega)\;\; \langle f', \phi\rangle \;:= - \langle f, \phi'\rangle$$ 
Which is also: $$\int_{\Omega} f'\phi = - \int_{\Omega}f\phi'$$
Hope this helps!

**Edit**: found this great topic: [Are weak derivatives and distributional derivatives different?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451746/are-weak-derivatives-and-distributional-derivatives-different?rq=1)